# ag grid: iterate over all row nodes after sorting

Tags: ag-grid

I want to iterate over all row nodes but in the current sorting order.
In the API (https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid/accessing-data/#accessing-row-node-api-methods) there are methods for iterating over all rows (*forEachNode()*) and over all filtered rows in sorted order (*forEachNodeAfterFilterAndSort()*)

Basically what I would need is a *forEachNodeAfterSort()* :)

Comment: so what exactly you are looking for?

Comment: As I stated in the question, I want to iterate over ALL the grid row nodes, but taking into consideration the sorted columns.